# GitHub Repository File Changes

Tags: github

I am subscribed to multiple GitHub repository channels and I am constantly seeing stuff like this:

```
File Changes
M .circleci/config.yml (2)
M .gitignore (2)
M doc/_static/style.css (9)
M doc/conf.py (4)
M doc/documentation.rst (2)
R examples/visualization/plot_make_report.py (8)
M mne/report.py (48)
M mne/tests/test_report.py (32)
```

What do the Ms and Rs mean when describing these file changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list is a summary of the changes that were done in a specific commit. These letters indicate what happened to the file next to them:

- `M` - modified
- `A` - added
- `D` - deleted
- `R` - renamed

and there are a few more.

These shortcuts are taken from the output for the `git status --short` command which you can read about more [in its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format).